# How to vote in a Facebook story?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to vote in a Facebook question through the Facebook API? I already know how to get the question's alternatives (lets say, like this: https://graph.facebook.com/10150462158592734). But how to actually vote in the question?

[Example of question](https://www.facebook.com/questions/10150462158592734/)

Comment: I'm sorry @OffBySome, but it not a duplicate. In fact, I had already seen that link that you just posted, but the questions have their differences. I don't want to CREATE a question, just vote in one of those. I thought it would be possible because the Android Facebook app does it.  Also, I noted that although you can vote inside the Facebook app, you cannot add a new answer/alternative.

Comment: 'because the Android Facebook app does it'...3rd party developers are limited to the public API, while the Android Facebook app is using a different (more robust) API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook questions API is currently read-only so you cannot vote or add questions via it.

Comment: Just added a comment. See it above.